# Compressing a string in Java

Tags: java

Not sure why my code isn't working. If I input `qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT`, I get `qw9w5e2ry5y4qE2ET3T` when I should be getting `q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T`.

Run-length encoding (RLE) is a simple "compression algorithm" (an algorithm which takes a block of data and reduces its size, producing a block that contains the same information in less space). It works by replacing repetitive sequences of identical data items with short "tokens" that represent entire sequences. Applying RLE to a string involves finding sequences in the string where the same character repeats. Each such sequence should be replaced by a "token" consisting of:

the number of characters in the sequence
the repeating character
If a character does not repeat, it should be left alone.

For example, consider the following string:

```
qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT
```

After applying the RLE algorithm, this string is converted into:

```
q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
```

In the compressed string, `"9w"` represents a sequence of 9 consecutive lowercase `"w"` characters. `"5e"` represents 5 consecutive lowercase `"e"` characters, etc.

Write a program that takes a string as input, compresses it using RLE, and outputs the compressed string. Case matters - uppercase and lowercase characters should be considered distinct. You may assume that there are no digit characters in the input string. There are no other restrictions on the input - it may contain spaces or punctuation. There is no need to treat non-letter characters any differently from letters.

```
    public class Compress{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String str = IO.readString();
        int count = 0;
        String result = "";

        for (int i=1; i<=str.length(); i++) {
            char a = str.charAt(i-1);
            count = 1;

            if (i-2 >= 0) {
            while (i<=str.length() && str.charAt(i-1) == str.charAt(i-2)) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            }
            if (count==1) {
                result = result.concat(Character.toString(a));
            }
            else {
                result = result.concat(Integer.toString(count).concat(Character.toString(a)));
            }
        }
        IO.outputStringAnswer(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be starting at position `0` instead of `1`?  Java is zero indexed

Comment: @MadProgrammer, no. I get the following error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: There's a problem with the condition in your `while`.  I think you should try debugging it yourself, though, instead of us giving you the answer.  If you aren't using an IDE with a debugger, try adding some `System.out.println`s to see what characters are being compared and when.

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging your code??

Comment: I still think you logic is around backwards, but that probably has more to do with how I would approach the problem...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call the characters "character 1 through character N" instead of "character 0 through character N-1", and then trying to adjust by subtracting 1 from the index.  Although you can make this work, it makes things more difficult and will probably lead to more errors.  It's best to get in the habit of thinking of strings and arrays as starting at position 0.  Don't worry, it will start coming naturally after a little while.

Comment: The problem is you're doing 'backward' checking. If you look at the intended result, it's clear that it should be doing 'forward' checking. You need to check if the character in front of 'a' is the same, not behind 'a'.

Comment: When `i == 2`, `str.charAt(i - 1) == 'w'`, but `str.charAt(i - 2) == 'q'` ??

Comment: Jos - you probably spoon fed him too much too quickly; Frederico could have worked this out on his own.  @Federico - The comments are providing good advice, -think- about them.  IMO, the problem that waves its hand "me me, I'm wrong" is starting your index at 1, not 0.  I don't care that starting at 0 caused and error; fix that.  Personally I would go with a variable outside the loop, 'lastChar' or some such to be my memory rather than tricky "-1" or "-2" ideas.  To me there is **much** to be said for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start at zero, and look forward:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String str = IO.readString();
    int count = 0;
    String result = "";

    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char a = str.charAt(i);
        count = 1;

        while (i + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }

        if (count == 1) {
            result = result.concat(Character.toString(a));
        } else {
            result = result.concat(Integer.toString(count).concat(Character.toString(a)));
        }
    }

    IO.outputStringAnswer(result);
}
```

Some outputs:

```
qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT => q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
qqwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT => 2q8w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
qqwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTXZ => 2q8w5e2rt5y4qw2ErTXZ
aaa => 3a
abc => abc
a => a
```